# Protect computer from usb device

Tags: usb

I need to plug a cctv style camera via usb on my computer in order to read what it recorded.

In general, how can I protect the computer I plug a usb device into, if I am worried the USB device might contain malicious code (e.g. malicious firmware from the manufacturer itself)?

Note that my question is different from this other [one](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/134458/how-does-one-properly-check-foreign-usb-drives-before-getting-them-in-your-netwo) which refers only to usb drives, whereas mine relates to USB devices (camera). Also the context is different (home versus hospital).

Comment: Do it on a machine you don't care about? (kind of like sheepdip)

Comment: @SmokeDispenser I think OPs Question is not a duplicate of my Question. I was refering to USB Storage and cleansing ob files on it whereas OPs Question referes to a USB Camera that is not mounted as a Storage Device

Comment: to be clear, the attack vector you want to protect yourself of is a possbly malicous firmeware of said usb camera (as it is not mounted as a storage divice? if not, please clarify where you suspect the malicious code

Comment: Hi Martin, my main concern is indeed of malicious firmware from the usb camera.

Comment: @DevShark Without RE the device you wouldn't be able to tell.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. What is RE?

Answer (score 0):

If you are really worried that there may be some malware on a removable device than your best bet is probably to run a live linux disk to check the device.  This will give you the ability to access / scan any devices without putting your local hard disk at risk.